# Message driven bean : Return message to queue and stop listening to queue

Tags: java, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

I have message driven bean which listen to the queue. There are more than one listener to this queue (from different contexts - different ear files). All I need to do is, when message is received and it was received with bean from different ear that I want, return message to the queue and somehow tell JMS to not send me this message anymore.

I am running my application on Jboss AS 6 and using HornetQ.

Is there any easy and fast way how to do it ? 
What I tried was, that when I found out, that I am in "incorrect" context, I just call rollback method from MessageDrivenContext, which returns message to the queue, but the same bean was picked up again, so it return message to queue again and it repeats for a few times, until I reached maximum delivery attempts and message was then send to dead letter queue.

Comment: To me this sounds like a wrong queue-layout. If certain messages are not intended to be read by certain consumers, why not define more and different queues? Just rolling back and hoping, another consumer will get the message is ugly and not guaranteed to work - not to say its inefficient.

Comment: Try using a message selector